# Pyserial can't read 'large' data in multiple threads

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, buffer, pyserial

I've been trying to port a script to Windows from Linux that records data from a mic array via the serial port. The Linux version uses the `termios` module which isn't supported on Windows so I'm using `Pyserial` instead.

The script starts three `threads` which repeatedly put ~4MB of data per thread into a queue. My problem is that, with Pyserial, if each thread is reading more than the 4k receive `buffer` only one or none of the threads actually receives data from `.read()` Below is a little test script to demonstrate my problem.

```
numThreads = 3
readSize = 4128000
q = Queue.Queue()
comPort = serial.Serial(port = 'COM5', baudrate = 115200)

def read_task(port, threadID, readSize):
    q.put((threadID, comPort.read(readSize)))

threads = [threading.Thread(target=read_task, args=(i,) for i in range(numThreads)]
for t in threads:
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

while 1:
    try:
        _,item = q.get(False)
        print hex(ord(item[0]))
        print len(item)
    except Queue.Empty:
        break
```

At the end I print the hex value of the first byte of each queue element that I get. I do this because I know that if the thread was actually reading data, every byte would be a non-zero value.
So the output would look something like:

```
0x94
4128000
0x00
4128000
0x00
4128000
```

So the first thread to call read was able to read data and the other two weren't and just returned a string of 0x00's. Is there anything I can do to get multiple threads to read that much data at one time.

I took a look at the `kernel32.dll` functions that Pyserial uses in `serialwin32.py` to execute .read() but I have no experience working with win32 API and I'm still fairly new to python so I can't really figure where to go from here.

I was just told to try to edit the read function in serialwin32 so that it's "non-overlapping". I'm going to try it.

Comment: Why do you want to try to read from the port concurrently across threads? You won't be able to tell what order to put the data in when it gets delivered to the main thread, will you?

Comment: That's why the data is put in with a threadID. There's some sorting that happens in the full script.

Comment: If you read from a single port from multiple threads at the same time, Bad Things Happen.  Consider a version of the code that just reads data and processes it, all in a single main line of code.